# MOOC JAVA part 1 EXERCISE 101 (search functionality). Not getting the desired output

Tags: java, arraylist

So the exercise is : "Add to the class Library the methods public ArrayList searchByTitle(String title), public ArrayList searchByPublisher(String publisher) and public ArrayList searchByYear(int year). The methods return the list of books that match the given title, publisher or year."

We have to use contains() method.
This is what I have done so far

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String publisher;
    private int year;
    
    
    
    
    public Book(String title, String publisher, int year){
        this.title=title;
        this.publisher=publisher;
        this.year=year;
    }
    
    public String title(){
        return this.title;
    }
    public String publisher(){
        return this.publisher;
    }
    
    public int year(){
        return this.year;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return this.title+", "+ this.publisher+ ", "+this.year;
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library {

    private ArrayList<Book> books;
    
    
    public Library(){
        this.books=new ArrayList<Book>();
    }
    
    public void addBook(Book newBook){
        this.books.add(newBook);
    }
    
    public void printBooks(){
        for(Book book: books){
            System.out.println(book);
        }
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Book> searchByTitle(String title){
        ArrayList<Book> found=new ArrayList<Book>();
        for(Book book: books){
            if(books.contains(title)){
                found.add(book);
            }
        }
        
        
        return found;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Book> searchByPublisher (String publisher){
        ArrayList<Book> found=new ArrayList<Book>();
        for(Book book: books){
            if(books.contains(publisher)){
                found.add(book);
            }
        }
        
        
        return found;
    
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Book> searchByYear(int year){
        ArrayList<Book> found=new ArrayList<Book>();
        for(Book book: books){
            if(books.contains(year)){
                found.add(book);
            }
        }
        
        
        return found;
        
    }

}

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // test your program here

        Library Library = new Library();

        Library.addBook(new Book("Cheese Problems Solved", "Woodhead Publishing", 2007));
        Library.addBook(new Book("The Stinky Cheese Man and Other Fairly Stupid Tales", "Penguin Group", 1992));
        Library.addBook(new Book("NHL Hockey", "Stanley Kupp", 1952));
        Library.addBook(new Book("Battle Axes", "Tom A. Hawk", 1851));

        ArrayList<Book> result = Library.searchByTitle("Cheese");
        for (Book book : result) {
            System.out.println(book);
        }

        System.out.println("---");
        for (Book book : Library.searchByPublisher("Penguin Group  ")) {
            System.out.println(book);
        }

        System.out.println("---");
        for (Book book : Library.searchByYear(1851)) {
            System.out.println(book);
        }

    }
}
```

Whats wrong with my search methods? The only thing it prints is "---". Any suggestions how to do this. I am a beginner in programming, and they want me to use `ArrayList<Book> found` in the search methods.

Comment: `if(books.contains(title))`? How can a list of _books_ contain a _title_ (or a publisher or a year)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(books.contains(year))`, `if(books.contains(title))` and `if(books.contains(publisher))` will never be true because `books` is an `ArrayList` that contains instances of `Book` class.

You probably meant to do the following:

**search by year**

```
if(book.year() == year) {
   found.add(book);
}
```

**search by publisher**

```
if(book.publisher().equals(publisher)) {
   found.add(book);
}
```

**search by title**

```
if(book.title().equals(title)) {
   found.add(book);
}
```

In search by title functionality, you could also use `.contains()` method if you not only want matching titles but also those book titles which contain `title` as a sub-string.

```
if(book.title().contains(title)) {
   found.add(book);
}
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   String str = "In Search of Lost Tim";
  
   System.out.println(str.contains("In Search of Lost Tim"));   // true
   System.out.println(str.contains("Lost Tim"));                // true
   System.out.println(str.contains("In Search"));               // true
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help! It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

In your methods *searchByTitle*, *searchByPublisher* and *searchByYear*, you are searching for the string in the *Books* list instead of your *book* object. It should be

```
public ArrayList<Book> searchByTitle(String title){
    ArrayList<Book> found=new ArrayList<Book>();
    for(Book book: books){
        if(book.title().contains(title)){
            found.add(book);
        }
    }
    
    
    return found;
}
```

Similarly for the other methods.For searching by year, you can do a straight up ==

Comment: The `Book` class does not have a method `contains`!

Comment: My bad. Updated my answer.

Comment: `book` class doesn't have a `getTitle` method as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Please, do not wildly type and guess. Your _answer_ is still wrong. `book.title()` returns a `String` that has a `contains` method, though, but obviously `equals` is the method OP wanted to use.